Unknown file extension ".vue" error on Heroku
I'm facing a file extension error for a Vue3 app on Heroku
The build is complete but then i get this error :
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".vue" for /app/src/App.vue
at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:160:9)
at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:203:36)
at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:143:22)
at async ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:7)
at async ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:278:45) {
code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
main.js :
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')

package.json
    {
      "name": "myApp",
      "type": "module",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "start": "node src/main.js"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "vue": "^3.0.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.15",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.15",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.15",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
          "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
          "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
          "eslint:recommended"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
          "parser": "babel-eslint"
        },
        "rules": {}
      },
      "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not dead"
      ]
    }

Procfile
web:node src/main.js


Does it work if you build it locally?

it does work locally yes. i run it with "npm run serve"

serve is pretty much dev workflow. When I say build, it's more of a build && start.

Also, why do you want to host your Vue app on Heroku? You don't really need a server for a static JS app nowadays. You could try to host it on Netlify/Vercel/Cloudflare pages, best part is that it's free.

Thank you for the advice ! I managed to have it working by changing two things. web: npm run start in the procfile and "start": "serve -s dist" in the package.json and also serve as a dependency.

@kissu I’d be wary about claiming the likes of Vercel are “free” when there have been plenty of stories recently of people naïvely believing the same, only to be hit with bills in the thousands.

@MartinBean yeah I know but at the end of the day, any platform can overcharge you if you don't consider the platform. Heroku will not be shy of sending you a big invoice if it's in their benefit and doesn't look too obvious of a scam. I don't really like using Vercel either, prefer the 2 only ones. Could also recommend Coolify etc, but that's besides the main point of my answer. So yeah, I did not brought the politics in my comment, just shared the fact that you can host a JS frontend framework for free nowadays. This also happens a lot with AWS for example, doesn't make AWS a bad service.
